# Express - trying to redirect after user successfully logs in

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm clearly not getting some core Node concept. After validating a user from the database, the database  returns an object("pass_to_html"). I want to render the results of that object onto a new page that is using handlebars.

My abbreviated code from login_handler.js (the server js doing the validating and pushing and pulling from the database):

```
function getTheeToDashboard(pass_to_html){
  app.post('/dashboard',function(req,res, next){
    res.redirect('/dashboard')
    res.render('dashboard', {view: dashboard, trainer_name: pass_to_html.trainer_data.trainer});
  })
}
```

from dashboard.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('dashboard')
});
```

from app.js:

```
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
```

from dashboard.hbs:

```
<h1> Welcome  {{trainer_name}}! </h1>
```

I don't get any errors, but clearly the app.htmlVerb does not engage. I've tried app.get, app.put and app.post.

**EDIT: After installing connect-flash-plus here are my revised settings but still no joy. I would think the app would redirect to the dashbaord page and display a message, but nothing. **

App.js

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash-plus');

var app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
   cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
   resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(flash());
```

login handler:

```
function getTheeToDashboard(pass_to_html){
  app.get('/flash',function(req,res){
    req.flash('info','Flash is back!')
    res.redirect('/dashboard')
  })
}
```

dashboard.js:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('dashboard',{messages: req.flash('info')})
});
```

Comment: why does your dashboard.js not match on /dashboard where you are redirecting to?  shouldn't it be:

`router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('dashboard',{messages: req.flash('info')})
});`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot both redirect and render a new page in the same request.

A redirect is a response to one request and tells the client to make another request.

Then the client can make another request to which you send another response. It's a two-step process. (If you want to make a redirect.)

You need to provide the correct data to your template in the GET handler of the target route that the redirect redirects to, not in the POST handler of the source route from which the redirect redirects from.

You can use the `connect-flash` module to pass data between those two requests if you want but you can also use the session data in the secind request's handler.

See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash-plus
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash-light
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash-redis

There are good example in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, this should work, but I'm not there yet. I looked at each of these and the only one that installed semi-cleanly was connect flash plus. I got it "working"" but am still back to trying to figure out what goes where.  Even following their example did not change anything. Here are my revised settings.